# Erro ao listar dados do banco - JPA2 e Hibernate / JSF

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Erro do console no eclipse

> ```
> mar 27, 2018 2:05:24 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
> GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/Fornecedor.xhtml]
> javax.el.ELException: /Fornecedor.xhtml @29,86 value="#{fornecedorBean.listaFornecedor}": Error reading [listaFornecedor] on type [bean.FornecedorBean]
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
>     at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:730)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1809)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:483)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:472)
>     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:82)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:826)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1131)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:620)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:81)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
>     at repository.FornecedorRepository.buscaTodas(FornecedorRepository.java:28)
>     at bean.FornecedorBean.getListaFornecedor(FornecedorBean.java:94)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
>     at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>     at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     ... 39 more
>
> mar 27, 2018 2:05:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
> GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/Venda_Estoque] threw exception [NONE] with root cause
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NONE
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:620)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.<init>(QueryImpl.java:81)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
>     at repository.FornecedorRepository.buscaTodas(FornecedorRepository.java:28)
>     at bean.FornecedorBean.getListaFornecedor(FornecedorBean.java:94)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
>     at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
>     at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:730)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1809)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndexWithoutRowStatePreserved(UIData.java:483)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:472)
>     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:82)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:826)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:1131)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

FornecedorRepository

```
public class FornecedorRepository {

    private EntityManager manager ;

    public FornecedorRepository (EntityManager manager ) {
        this.manager = manager ;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <Fornecedor> buscaTodas() {
        Query query = this.manager.createQuery(" SELECT e FROM Fornecedor e");
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

FornecedorBean

```
@ManagedBean
public class FornecedorBean {

    private List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedor;

    public List<Fornecedor> getListaFornecedor() {
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("venda_estoque");
            EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

            FornecedorRepository fr = new FornecedorRepository(manager);
            fr.buscaTodas();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaFornecedor;
    }

    public void setListaFornecedor(List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedor) {
        this.listaFornecedor = listaFornecedor;
    }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode nos passar o resultado do `mvn dependency:tree` e o conteúdo do pom.xml? (assumindo que esteja usando maven). Este problema costuma aparecer quando tem algo errado no classpath

Comment: não estou utilizando maven

Comment: Está com as libs do hibernate direto no projeto? Mostra todos os JARs que estão no projeto então.

Comment: sim eu coloquei as libs do hibernate. Coloquei as um print dos jars utilizado

Answer (score 1):

Verifique a versão da biblioteca hibernate-commons-annotations que está 4.0.1 enquanto as outras estão 4.1.6.

Uma outra coisa a linha:

```
fr.buscaTodas();
```

Deveria ser:

```
listaFornecedor = fr.buscaTodas();
```